# I want to add some images in my apps by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I want to add some images in my apps by android studio. but its not working, please help me how can i add more images.

deign and XML Screenshot uploaded.

Please help me,

Thanks
Miraz

Screenshots:
[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwFox.png)
[xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m44iN.png)

Comment: `LinearLayout` is LITERALLY linear, so you should nest them in order to achieve this.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: I am new with android . i don't know here for this design whats layout can i use. please help me. when i add more image here show only 3 images

Comment: change the app:srcCompat attribute to android:src in the ImageView and change the orientation of your Layout to vertical. You should try to find out the solutions of your own by searching and learning from internet!

Comment: @Nikhya  i did it but now hide all images

Comment: Right.. now I saw ur design! A linearLayout will not be suitable for what u want to do. Use Relative layout to arrange your images in abstract manner. Go for Udacity Material Design course to get knowledge of Material design strategy of android

Comment: – Nikhya thanks,
Now its working. one more questions, How can i make image size in parentage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your **Linear Layout** to **Relative Layout** to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.
i changed it.
Now its working. one more questions, How can i make image size in parentage?

Comment: If you are looking to add multiple images in a single line or a group, you can use android:layout_weight="<value>", change the <Value> to your desired value.

Comment: Can i use the value in parentage?

Comment: As far as I know, it may not be possible.
post your code in a fiddle so that anyone of us can edit it as per your requirement!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your layout type to **Linear Layout** or **Relative Layout** and "YES" you can set value in parentage like this:-

```
ImageView image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
calulate(image_view);



private void calulate(View v) 
{
    int imgWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int imgHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (0.25*imgHeight);//You can change 0.25 with your value
    v.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (0.25*imgWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your xml add Src in this way you set image,to add your image in drawable or in mipmap folder as per its resolution.

`<ImageView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>`